# How to pass cookie through open feign

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cookies

I have two spring boot projects and want to pass the cookie from one project to another

1st spring boot project:

```
class SomeClass() {
    @Autowired
    private MyClient myClient;

     someMethod1() {
       myClient.getDetails();
    }
}

@FeignClient(value = "abc", url = "http://someexample.com/emp/user")
public interface MyClient {

    @GetMapping(value = "/details")
    void getDetails();

}
```

2nd spring boot project:

```
@GetMapping("/details")
void someDetails(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "user");
        if (cookie != null) {
}
}
```

Problem is that the cookie is available in the 1st project. When the feign calls the other project method, the someDetails method does not have the cookie with the name "user" has such the cookie value is null and the if condition fails. How can I pass it?

Comment: did u figure it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the most proper way to achive it, but you can send cookie via corresponding HTTP header like this

```
@GetMapping(value = "/details")
void getDetails(@RequestHeader("Cookie") String cookie);
```

More about HTTP header "Cookie" [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie)